# How to calculate flight line intersections?

Tags: qgis

I am new to GIS, and I have flight lines and I am interested in determining the crossover or intersection of those lines. Can I use QGIS for that and what would be the procedures for doing it?

Answer (score 4):

Presumings these are the flights:

[image]

[image]

You can access the `Vector > Analysis Tools > Line intersections` menu:

[image]

And here's the result (using QGIS 2.0.1):

[image]

[image]